# RJ45 Crimp Tool Difference

Tags: networking

I have used my RJ45 crimp tool for Cat5e before without issue, now I wanted to crimp a Cat6a plug and ran into some issues.

I researched a bit before and every source I came across said I could use the crimp tool for any RJ45 plug. I was almost sure that this is wrong and the crimp tool would destroy the plug, and when I actually wanted to crimp it, to no surprise, it did destroy it.

The Cat6a plug has no plastic "wedge" that is pushed down by the "nose" on the crimp pliers, like the Cat5e, so there definitely is a difference between plugs.

[image]

So what is the actual standard here? Remove the nose for Cat6 plugs?

PS: I suppose I can unscrew the "nose" on the tool, but why is this difference not mentioned anywhere and everybody is reiterating this "it works for everything" nonsense?

Comment: The crimp tool should work on both plugs. Can you include a picture of each in your question?

Comment: Probably with modification, but not out of the box. See picture.

Comment: Is there a wedge under the Cat6a metal shield? Can the shield be temporarily removed while crimping, then replaced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That tool will work with shielded plugs. It has an adjustable strain latch presser bar. Remove it otherwise it will crush the plug.

Comment: As suspected. Still, obviously it should be mentioned there is DEFINITELY a difference in plug types.